# Difference between GNU Make builder and FSL Make builder

Tags: makefile, embedded, gnu-make

I have the 2 options  above in the IDE I'm using - S32 Design Studio. What is the difference between the two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Builders in the IDE are not just selection of an external tool, they actually create the makefiles out of the configuration settings in the preference / settings dialogs.

In the end, both call just make.

But the FSL Make Builder takes much more into consideration:

- processor expert settings
- processor cores and hw-accelerator (e.g. SPT) build configs and tooling
- additional SDKs
- Flash / RAM configurations (e.g. create different linker scripts for the memory layout)
- create launch configs